# Leaflet Map and Layer don't move at the same time when zooming in / out

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a small issue in the application I am building currently, and I can't figure out what's the problem. 
I am using leaflet for displaying the map, with a Google Maps layer as a map.

My problem is that **when I am zooming in or out of the map, the actual maps move directly but it takes almost a second before the markers layer gets updated too**.

You can reproduce my problem easily [**on this test server**](http://spo2tu.be:8002), by choosing on of the points of interest, and zooming in or out when the  points are displayed.

I haven't found any reference of this problem on the internet so far. Do you have any idea where this could come from ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is using a Google Maps layer, which means it wraps the Google Maps API. Since the Google Maps API zooms at a different speed than Leaflet, you see this effect.

There's no quick fix here: it's just not a very good idea to use the Google Maps API within Leaflet, technically or legally. Either use Leaflet with tiles that can be used directly with it - OSM, MapQuest, Stamen, Mapbox - or use the Google Maps API.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I don't think there is a legal issue. I am required to use the google maps overlay because I use their advanced APIs. The google logo is currently missing, though. This is a test server.

Comment: No, [there is a legal issue.](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/issues/48)

Comment: Good reading. Thanks for the extra information. Hope the exception for OL will also apply to Leaflet one day or the other :S.